# The best constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c||x||_p \leq ||x||_q\leq C||x||_p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Taken from Conway's A course in Functional Analysis Chapter 3 Section 1 Problem 3

Problem statement: For $1\leq p < \infty$ and $x = (x_1,...,x_d)$ in $\mathbb{F}^d$, define $||x||_p = \left[\sum_{j = 1}^d|x_j|^p\right]^{1/p}$; define $||x||_\infty = \sup\{|x|_j: 1\leq j \leq d\}$. Show that all of these norms are equivalent. For $1\leq p, q \leq \infty$, what are the best constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c||x||_p \leq ||x||_q\leq C||x||_p$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{F}^d$.

I went straight to finding constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c||x||_p \leq ||x||_q\leq C||x||_p$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{F}^d$ since the equivalence of th enormous would immediately follow from this. However, I'm not even sure where to begin. I thought of trying to let $x_j$ all be the same for a possible candidate for $c$ or $C$,but this doesn't seem too promising.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here are some tips: Assume either $p<q$ or $q<p$ and stick with that. Take a look at Jensen's inequality or Hölders inequality and play with them to get some general inequalites (for example remember that $x^\alpha$ is convex if $\alpha >1$). Take a look at the vectors $x=(1,1,...,1)$ and $x=(1,0,0,...,0)$ as important cases to show that the constant you get is best constant (ie show $\|x\|_q ≥ C\|x\|_q$ for some $C$ and then check that for $x=(1,1,...,1)$ this $≥$ becomes $=$, verifying that $C$ was the best constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is tempting, I do not think that Hölder's inequality will help you in this case. Consider this rather obvious inequality (remember that $\lvert x_j \rvert \leq \lVert x \rVert_\infty$ for all $j$):
$$
\lVert x \rVert_p = \left (\sum_{j = 1}^d \lvert x_j \rvert \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \left( d \lVert x \rVert_\infty^p \right)^\frac{1}{p} = d^\frac{1}{p} \lVert x \rVert_\infty
$$
Now note that there has to be some $\ell \in \lbrace 1, ..., d \rbrace$ such that $\lVert x \rVert_\infty = \lvert x_\ell \rvert$. So:
$$
\lVert x \rVert_\infty = \lvert x_\ell \rvert = (\lvert x_\ell \rvert^q)^\frac{1}{q} \leq \left( \sum_{j = 1}^d \lvert x_j \rvert^q \right)^\frac{1}{q} = \lVert x \rVert_q
$$
If we combine all of this, we get
$$
c \lVert x \rVert_p \leq \lVert x \rVert_\infty \leq  \lVert x \rVert_q
$$
for $c := \frac{1}{d^\frac{1}{p}}$. If you reapply the above reasoning, you get:
$$
\lVert x \rVert_q \leq C \lVert x \rVert_p
$$
for $C := d^\frac{1}{q}$. This means:
$$
c \lVert x \rVert_p \leq \lVert x \rVert_\infty \leq  \lVert x \rVert_q \leq C \lVert x \rVert_p
$$
for the already defined constants $c, C > 0$. This proves the equivalence of the norms $\lVert \cdot \rVert_r$, $r \in [1, \infty]$.

I have not quite yet figured out whether these are the best constants.

Comment: I would have to disagree with your constants. Also if you plug in $(1,...,1)$ you do not get equality for the constants you have derived. (Remember $\|(1,...,1)\|_p = d^{1/p}$, so your inequality becomes $1 ≤ d^{1/q}≤ d^{1/q+1/p}$)

Comment: Okay I understand the point about $(1, ..., 1)$. I might have to edit that. But why do you disagree with the constants?

Comment: In the event $p<q$ I get $C=n^{1/p-1/q}$ and think $c=1$ but I haven't actually done the calculation.